# Implementation of QueryCache

Tags: sql, algorithm, caching, query-cache

Aside from doing a direct match on something like a whitespace normalized hash of a query, what might be a useful (but-not-necessarily-perfect) way to handle query cache in a partial manner? For example, let's take the following basic case:

```
SELECT
    Product,  # VARCHAR
    Revenue   # DOUBLE
FROM
    Sales
WHERE
    Country='US'
```

This potentially could be used as a 'base-cache' upon which a further query could be executed to potentially improve performance:

```
SELECT
    Product,  # VARCHAR
    Revenue   # DOUBLE
FROM
    Sales
WHERE
    Country='US' AND State='CA'
```

So, assuming the data in the `from` table(s) don't change, the following might serve as a starting point for determining cache:

- fields: [field:type, ...] // can be less but not more
- from: hash of table(s)+joins
- filters: [filter1, filter2, ...] // can be less but not more
- aggregations: [agg1, agg2, ...] // can be less but not more
- having: [having1, having2, ...] // can be less but not more
- order+limit+offset if limited result-set // can be less but not more

However, this becomes quite tricky when we think about something like the following case:

```
SELECT
    ProductGroup AS Product,  # Would produce a Product:VARCHAR hash
    Revenue   
FROM
    Sales
WHERE
    Country='US'
```

What might be a realistic starting point for how a partial- query cache could be implemented.

---

**Use case:** writing SQL to query data in a non-DBMS-managed source, such as a CSV file which will take ~20s or so to issue any query and we cannot create indexes on the file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/MED or Spark-like.

Comment: Are you using any real world DBMS (which you forgot to tag) and should this solve a real world performance problem? Then you likely just want to create indexes on `(country)` and `(country, state)` (or even include the projected column like `(country, product, revenue)` and `(country, state, product, revenue)` (or include `productgroup` as well or have an extra set of indexes for that)) and be done.

Comment: @stickybit not really it's more for querying a non-managed source, such as a CSV/Parquet/etc. file from a database (something like federated data access, where queries take a long time and no option for indexes).

Comment: OK. But why cannot you create indexes but caches?

Comment: @stickybit cache is the application layer. i.e., we store the cache data remotely so we don't even have to hit the file at all.

Comment: As I imagine it, you're programming said application layer? Then you could also implement (covering) indexes there?

Comment: You cannot optimnise SQL by ignoring it. The DBMS is smarter than you (in most cases)

Comment: Oh and of course you could load the data in a DBMS and *then* just use well tested and proven optimization strategies and implementations. There might even be solutions that help you to minimize the effort needed for loading and transformation.

Comment: @stickybit sure but what characteristics could you use of the query (after being parsed) to know that the correct data is there?

Comment: @stickybit I took a stab at it in an answer. Does that seem ok?

Comment: @wildplasser I tried to write a basic conceptual implementation in an answer. Does that seem like a valid approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following might be a good starting place for a basic cache implementation that allows the usage of a cache that can be further queried for refinements:

1. Start by substituting any udf's or cte's. The query itself needs to be self-contained.
2. Normalize whitespaces and capitalization.
3. Hash the entire query. This will be our starting place.
4. Remove the select fields and hash the rest of the query. Now store a hash of all the individual items in the select list.
5. For partial cache, generate a hash minus select fields, where, sort, and limit+offset. Hash the where's list (separated by AND), making sure no filter is contained in the cache that is not contained in the current query, the orderby, seeing if the data needs to be re-sorted, and the limit+offset number, making sure the limit+offset in the initial query is null or greater than the current query.

Here would be an example of how the data might look saved:

| Hash | 673c0185c6a580d51266e78608e8e9b2 |
| --- | --- |
| HashMinusFields | 41257d239fb19ec0ccf34c36eba1948e |
| HashOfFields | [dc99e4006c8a77025c0407c1fdebeed3, …] |
| HashMinusFieldsWhereOrderLimit | d50961b6ca0afe05120a0196a93726f5 |
| HashOfWheres | [0519669bae709d2efdc4dc8db2d171aa, ...] |
| HashOfOrder | 81961d1ff6063ed9d7515a3cefb0c2a5 |
| LimitOffset | null |

Now let's try a few examples, I will use human-readable hashes for easier readability:

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM Sales WHERE id=2
-- fullHash:   selectname,agefromsaleswhereid=2
-- selectless: fromsaleswhereid=2
-- hashoffields: [name, age]
-- minusfieldswhereorderlimit: null
-- hashofwheres:  [id=2, ]
-- hashororder: null
-- limitoffset: null

-- query1
select age FROM sales where id=2
-- selectless: fromsaleswhereid=2
-- fields: [age] OK, all fields contained in initial fields

-- query2
select age FROM sales where id=2 and country='us' order by id limit 100 
-- minusfieldswhereorderlimit: null
-- hashofwheres: [id=2, country=us] OK initial query does not contain any additional filters
-- limitoffset: 100 OK initial limitoffset is null (infinity)
-- hashorder: orderbyid
--> Can grab partial cache, need to apply one filter and re-sort/limit:
    --> SELECT * FROM <cache> WHERE country='us' order by id limit 100
```

Does the above seem like a valid initial implementation?